# Rust dxgcap convert print from Vec<dxgcap::BGRA8> to Vec<u8>

Tags: rust

Using crate dxgcap how can i save response of capture_frame fn to file using image crate.
I would also like to crop the images so it would be interesting to convert to a Vec

Note: capture_frame returns `Vec<dxgcap::BGRA8>` BGRA8 is  struct with r,g,b,a all are u8.

Answer (score 0):

Converting of types inside `Vec` is tricky, because `Vec` interacts with memory allocator and promises to report accurate allocation size and exact same alignment, which could differ between types. It's cumbersome and potentially unsafe.

If you only need to read the elements as a contiguous `u8` slice, then:

```rust
let bytes = std::slice::from_raw_parts(vec.as_ptr() as *const u8, vec.len() * 4);
```

If you control the types used, then check out the [bytemuck](https://lib.rs/bytemuck) crate which has traits for casting to and from bytes.